# Try and Except with Conditionals in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner and wrote the following program as part of a Python exercise:

```
try:
    hours = raw_input ('Enter number of hours \n')
    int(hours)
    rate = raw_input ('Enter your hourly rate \n')
    int(rate)
except:
    print 'Enter an integer value'
    quit()
if hours > 40:
    overtime = hours - 40
    base = 40*rate
    additional = overtime * (1.5 * rate) 
    print 'Your total wage including overtime is', additional + base
else:
    wage = rate * hours
    print 'Your total wage before tax is', wage
```

---

However, I receive a `TypeError in line 10 that reads unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

What's weird is when I enter hours say as 10 and rate as five, it should skip the first if statement and jump directly to the else...but for some reason that isn't happening. Also, when I made the first version of the same program without the try and except bit:

```
hours = float(raw_input('Enter number of hours \n'))
rate = float(raw_input('Enter your hourly rate \n'))
if hours > 40:
    overtime = hours - 40
    base = 40*rate
    additional = overtime * (1.5 * rate) 
    print 'Your total wage including overtime is', additional + base
else:
    wage = rate * hours
    print 'Your total wage before tax is', wage
```

---

This works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Conversion from **string** to **int** is not saved into **hours**. To achieve this do this:

```
hours=int(hours) # this is in the 3rd line of your code. Do the same for rate
```

Answer (score 1):

`int(hours)` is not in-place. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

> ***Return*** an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given

You need to re-assign it back to the variable

```
hours = int(hours)
```

Comment: Very interesting...hardly realized. Thanks!